# How to print to console when using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cout

I'm using Qt4 and C++ for making some programs in computer graphics. I need to be able to print some variables in my console at run-time, not debugging, but `cout` doesn't seem to work even if I add the libraries. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on cout not working because that should certainly work. Do you get a compile error. Can you show a code example of cout that isn't working for you? Also explain how you are running the application. Are you running it from a console or from within an IDE and not seeing output to its output window?

Comment: Just for completeness: @ArnoldSpence - without libraries, I get `error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope`; with iostream, I get `error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](((std::basic_ostream<char>&)(& std::cout)), ...`; using the commands in the answer instead works fine.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: In this case, you should explicitly specify that those "variables" are Qt-specific objects (such as `QString`).

Answer (score 243, accepted):

If it is good enough to print to `stderr`, you can use the following streams originally intended for debugging:

```
#include<QDebug>

//qInfo is qt5.5+ only.
qInfo() << "C++ Style Info Message";
qInfo( "C Style Info Message" );

qDebug() << "C++ Style Debug Message";
qDebug( "C Style Debug Message" );

qWarning() << "C++ Style Warning Message";
qWarning( "C Style Warning Message" );

qCritical() << "C++ Style Critical Error Message";
qCritical( "C Style Critical Error Message" );

// qFatal does not have a C++ style method.
qFatal( "C Style Fatal Error Message" );
```

Though as pointed out in the comments, bear in mind qDebug messages are removed if `QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT` is defined

If you need stdout you could try something like this (as Kyle Strand has pointed out):

```
QTextStream& qStdOut()
{
    static QTextStream ts( stdout );
    return ts;
}
```

You could then call as follows:

```
qStdOut() << "std out!";
```

Comment: I asked ,while not debugging, there must be a function that allows me to write messages in console during runtime, not during debugging.

Comment: Despite its name, that function is not related to debugging with a debugger. It is a convenience function that Qt provides for sending output to stderr that can be removed from compilation with a define. So it is an alternative for achieving output to the console at runtime.

Comment: Thank you all a lot, I'm using this :). I guess there is no need then for me to write any of the code I used. Thanks! This has been super usefull.

Comment: Please don't use qDebug for all console output. Only use it for true debug prints use qWarning, qCritical and qFatal for errors and warnings. Because qDebug statements can be removed when compiling with QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT to save performance and stop the application from cluttering up the output.

Comment: QTextStream dooesn't flush the output, so if it used to show dynamic process, it will stall until program closes

Comment: So add an appropriate flush statement to the answer?

Comment: If you add << endl, the stream will also be flushed. This is not the case if you use "\n"

Answer (score 167):

I found [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/33506-where-is-cout-in-Qt-Creator) most useful:

```
#include <QTextStream>

QTextStream out(stdout);
foreach(QString x, strings)
    out << x << endl;
```

Comment: Agreed. stderr is for, well, errors (and debugging). This should be the accepted answer because it's the only one which uses stdout AND qt.

Comment: If you incorporate the information from Goz's answer about how to print errors/warnings, along with a bit of information (sadly lacking from Goz's answer but present in the comments below it) about what `qDebug()` etc actually do, this will be by far the superior answer (IMO it's already superior since OP is asking for something to replace `std::cout`, but 40ish voters appear not to agree).

Comment: `QTextStream qStdout() { return {stdout}; }` might be a useful way to wrap this, consistent with `qWarning()` etc.  And maybe some `static` state to avoid temporary streamage?

Comment: One downside of QTextStream, is it doesn't print out all the Q-Types as easily as QDebug or QInfo, etc.  For example: `qDebug() << widget->geometry();` v. `out << widget->geometry().x() << ", " << widget->geometry().y() //....`

Comment: And should I instantiate this only once? Or can I do this per pethod?

Comment: @TomášZato: as you like... I would probably declare an inline in a .h (maybe toStdout.h), so would be easy to call

Comment: Note that using << endl will also flush the stream, while "\n" does not.

Comment: @MiB_Coder: that's by design in stdlib::streams, no ? Also, right now I don't remember if "\n" does the platform specific translation (at least on Windows, endl should be "\r\n").

Comment: @CapelliC: As discussed in the other answers, if you write out() << "Hello\n", it will print when out is destroyed (e.g. at the end of the program), while out() << "Hello" << endl will print immediately. The c++ standard on the other hand says: endl is equivalent with "\n".

Answer (score 37):

Add this to your project file:

```
CONFIG += console
```

Comment: There was no information given in the question regarding which build system is being used. This is only relevant when using `qmake`.

Answer (score 37):

#### Writing to `stdout`

If you want something that, like `std::cout`, writes to your application's standard output, you can simply do [the following](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/33506-where-is-cout-in-Qt-Creator) ([credit to CapelliC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17649741/1858225)):

```
QTextStream(stdout) << "string to print" << endl;
```

If you want to avoid creating a temporary `QTextStream` object, follow Yakk's suggestion in the comments below of creating a function to return a `static` handle for `stdout`:

```
inline QTextStream& qStdout()
{
    static QTextStream r{stdout};
    return r;
}

...

foreach(QString x, strings)
    qStdout() << x << endl;
```

---

**Remember** to `flush` the stream periodically to ensure the output is actually printed.

#### Writing to `stderr`

Note that the above technique can also be used for other outputs. However, there are more readable ways to write to `stderr` ([credit to Goz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3886128/1858225) and the comments below his answer):

```
qDebug() << "Debug Message";    // CAN BE REMOVED AT COMPILE TIME!
qWarning() << "Warning Message";
qCritical() << "Critical Error Message";
qFatal("Fatal Error Message");  // WILL KILL THE PROGRAM!
```

`qDebug()` is closed if `QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT` is turned on at compile-time.

(Goz notes in a comment that for non-console apps, these can print to a different stream than `stderr`.)

---

**NOTE:** All of the Qt print methods [assume that `const char*` arguments](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#operator-lt-lt-16) are ISO-8859-1 encoded strings with terminating `\0` characters.

Comment: `QTextStream qStdout() { static QTextStream r{stdout}; return r; }`?

Comment: @Yakk Good suggestion! I'll incorporate into my answer.

Comment: qFatal() gets an error when compiling with QT5. a read a post, that it wasn't ment to (be there/work) anyway... don't use it! :)

Comment: @relascope I'm not sure what you mean by "gets an error," but the documentation does indicate that it will cause a core dump on Unix, so I've indicated that in the answer.

Comment: /* sorry, didn't find the article anymore but */ qFatal("Hello Fatal"); / is the way to use it (on QT5), it send SIGABRT !!! when compiling */ qFatal() << "Hello Fatal"; / ./qfatal/main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)': ../qfatal/main.cpp:13:12: error: no matching function for call to 'QMessageLogger::fatal()' qFatal() << "Hello Fatal"; [...] qlogging.h:107:10: note: candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided */

Comment: @relascope Ah, I see, the function itself is supposed to take the error message string. I've edited my example; all four lines now compile correctly and behave as expected.

Comment: You don't want to be suggesting that people create a new text stream on every iteration of the loop. Even if the text stream had an optimization to make this cheap (it doesn't), it still would have very bad code smell to it. Obviously I just realized that you also comment that it's wrong. Here's what I suggest: I rolled back the edit. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @KubaOber No problem. I actually *did* hope (if not assume) that since it's using an already-existing text stream in the constructor, it *would* have an optimization to make this cheap. But either way the "right" way to do this is indeed the function-returning-reference-to-static approach. Thanks for reminding me of this; I'll edit to simplify a bit.

Comment: `stdout` is not a text stream, it's a pointer a C file object. Apart from the buffers in `QTextStream`, you're also at the very least constructing and destructing a temporary `QIODevice` every time, too. That's how a `QTextStream` accesses the file: by wrapping it in a `QIODevice` subclass (I forget which one, probably `QFile`).

Comment: @KubaOber Ah, that also clarifies why `stdout` isn't from a namespace, which I'd been wondering but hadn't looked into.

Comment: @KyleStrand The C++98 standard, in [lib.c.files] says that stderr, stdin and stdout are macros and obviously macros can't be in any namespace. From [Jakub Jelinek](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52195#c1). That also tells you why macros are so bad, and unless you absolutely need them, they have no place in modern C++

Comment: @KyleStrand E.g. in C++ if you include `<cstdio>`, you can't use any symbols named stdin, stdout, stderr, in *any* namespace :( They behave like keywords, except that the compiler will give you weird diagnostics and/or silently miscompile your code. E.g. on OS X/clang, a public `foo::stdin` symbol becomes `foo::__stdinp`, and any code that might use it will not link iff it happens not to include `<cstdio>`. Global namespace pollution by macros is frightening, frankly said.

Comment: @KubaOber I actually use them quite a bit, mostly to work around what I perceive as shortcomings in the language. For instance, I have a macro that simply takes the name of a member function and creates a lambda that copy-captures `this` and otherwise duplicates the member function's signature. I find this easier than [remembering the oddities of generic capturing in C++14 for various compilers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34889310/1858225) and more readable and typesafe than using `std::bind(&ClassName::functionName, this, std::placeholders::_1, .... )`.

Comment: @KyleStrand This can be done with a function, no need for a macro :)

Comment: @KubaOber If nothing else, the function would require the 'this' pointer explicitly as one of its arguments, and I believe you'd need the fully scoped name of the function with ampersand function-pointer syntax as well. That's simply not as nice as a simple macro.

Comment: @KubaOber In other words, I find `BIND_MEMBER_TO_THIS(myMemberFunc)` much more readable than `BindMemberToPtr(this, &MyClass::myMemberFunc)`.

Comment: @KubaOber Another example that's just come up: I realize that casting away `const` is dangerous and should therefore be explicit, but in the case where a `const` member function calls a non-`const` member function, I find it inelegant and redundant to have to re-specify what class I'm in just to cast away `const`. But the syntax for inferring the type and stripping `const` looks like this: `const_cast<std::remove_const<std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type>::type&>(*this)`. Seriously, there is no reason to type that multiple times.

Comment: @KyleStrand Can't you use a function for that? `template <typename C> constexpr typename std::remove_const<typename std::remove_reference<C>::type>::type& no_const(C* c)
{ return const_cast<typename std::remove_const<typename std::remove_reference<C>::type>::type&>(*c); }` **Use:** `no_const(this).method()`. You could inject that function as a method into the class, and then you wouldn't even need to pass `this`: `Foo& no_const() const { return ::no_const(this); }` *No typos, I promise.*

Comment: @KubaOber After I wrote that, I realized that indeed the `std::remove_....` functions I'm using are indeed *functions*, so it should be possible to write a template function that could do the rest for me. I'll admit I still think that's way more complicated than it ought to be, but it's certainly not the argument for macros that I thought it was! Thank you.

Comment: I naively upvoted this answer before trying and I cannot take that back. But it does not work. When I replace `qStdout` with `QTextStream(stdout)` it works, so static initialization is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @TomášZato I've tested this, so I know it works. When you say it "does not work", do you mean you get a compile error, or you don't get any output? Are you ensuring that the stream is flushed?

Comment: It does not generate any output at all. Once I replaced it with `QTextStream` constructor it started working. I do not understand what do you mean by flushing the stream.

Comment: @TomášZato Output is buffered and may not actually print until the stream is *flushed* (which simply means that the application forces all buffered output to be written, and *stops execution* until that has happened). This is done automatically by the `QTextStream` destructor, which may be why you're seeing output when you use the constructor directly to create temporary objects. To flush manually, just call `qStdout().flush()`.

Comment: @TomášZato (Buffering/flushing I/O is very standard; you should research it on your own if you still have questions about it.)

Comment: @TomášZato I have made an edit that includes a note to `flush` the streams. If you are still having difficulties, feel free to remove your upvote (votes are unlocked when a post is edited).

Comment: Is the part about making a function necessary? It seems the source you reference said it was a hypothetical: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287692/the-nuclear-option-massively-editing-the-accepted-answer/287701#comment167242_287701 I'd like to upvote this answer but I'm hesitant to believe that it's necessary to make a function that returns a static instance.

Comment: @Mitch Hm, reviewing those links and the Qt documentation, you're right; I don't see anything to indicate that there's any real known issue caused by temporary `QTextStream` objects. Edited.

Answer (score 22):

What variables do you want to print? If you mean QStrings, those need to be converted to c-Strings. Try:

```
std::cout << myString.toAscii().data();
```

Comment: @CoderaPurpa You need to add `#include <iostream>`

Comment: `myString.toUtf8().data()` is better because it prints Characters outside the ascii range. Chinese characters for example

Answer (score 11):

It also has a syntax similar to prinft, e.g.:

```
qDebug ("message %d, says: %s",num,str);
```

Very handy as well

Answer (score 7):

Go the Project's `Properties -> Linker-> System -> SubSystem`, then set it to `Console(/S)`.

Comment: This (like Kyle Lutz's answer) is build-system specific.

Answer (score 5):

What about including *iostream library* and precise that **cout** is an object of **std** like this :

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
```

Comment: IMHO this is the best answer. If you want to send output to Standard output just use the standard C++ iostream std::cout...

Answer (score 1):

If you are printing to stderr using the stdio library, a call to `fflush(stderr)` should flush the buffer and get you real-time logging.

Answer (score 1):

For Qt5 QString must be converted, for example:

```
QString sResultText = lblLineEdit->text(); //<--text from QLineEdit
qInfo(sResultText.toUtf8().data()); //<--show converted result
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after studying several examples on the Internet describing how to output messages from a GUI in Qt to stdout, I have refined a working stand-alone example on redirecting messages to a console, via qDebug() and installing qInstallMessageHandler(). The console will be showed at the same time as the GUI and can be hidden if deemed necessary. The code is easy to integrate with existing code in your project. Here is the full sample and feel free to use it in any way as you like, as long as you adhere to the License GNU GPL v2. You have to use a form of some sort and a MainWindow I think - otherwise the sample will run, but probably crash when forced to quit. Note: there is no way to quit via a close button or a menu close because I have tested those alternatives and the application will crash eventually every now and then. Without the close button the application will be stable and you can close it down from the main window. Enjoy!

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

//GNU GPL V2, 2015-02-07
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <windows.h>
#define CONSOLE_COLUMNS 80
#define CONSOLE_ROWS    5000
#define YOURCONSOLETITLE "Your_Console_Title"

typedef struct{

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX conScreenBuffInfoEX;

    HANDLE con_screenbuf;
    HWND hwndConsole;
    HMENU consoleMenu ;
    QString consoleTitle;

    QMessageBox mBox;
    QString localMsg;
    QString errorMessage;
    WINBOOL errorCode;

} consoleT;

static consoleT *console;

BOOL WINAPI catchCTRL( DWORD ctrlMsg ){

        if( ctrlMsg == CTRL_C_EVENT ){

            HWND hwndWin = GetConsoleWindow();
               ShowWindow(hwndWin,SW_FORCEMINIMIZE);
        }

    return TRUE;
}

void removeCloseMenu(){

    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        console->hwndConsole = FindWindowW( NULL, console->consoleTitle.toStdWString().data());

        if(console->hwndConsole != NULL)
            break;
    }

    if( !(console->errorCode = 0) && (console->hwndConsole == NULL))
            console->errorMessage += QString("\nFindWindowW error: %1 \n").arg(console->errorCode);

    if( !(console->errorCode = 0) &&  !(console->consoleMenu = GetSystemMenu( console->hwndConsole, FALSE )) )
        console->errorMessage += QString("GetSystemMenu error: %1 \n").arg(console->errorCode);

    if(!(console->errorCode = DeleteMenu( console->consoleMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND )))
           console->errorMessage += QString("DeleteMenu error: %1 \n").arg(console->errorCode);
}

void initialiseConsole(){

    console->conScreenBuffInfoEX.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX);
    console->consoleMenu = NULL;
    console->consoleTitle = YOURCONSOLETITLE;
    console->con_screenbuf = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    console->errorCode = 0;
    console->errorMessage = "";
    console->hwndConsole = NULL;
    console->localMsg = "";

    if(!(console->errorCode = FreeConsole()))
        console->errorMessage += QString("\nFreeConsole error: %1 \n").arg(console->errorCode);

    if(!(console->errorCode = AllocConsole()))
        console->errorMessage += QString("\nAllocConsole error: %1 \n").arg(console->errorCode);

    if( (console->errorCode = -1) && (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ==(console->con_screenbuf = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer( GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL))))
        console->errorMessage += QString("\nCreateConsoleScreenBuffer error: %1 \n").arg(console->errorCode);

    if(!(console->errorCode = SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(console->con_screenbuf)))
        console->errorMessage += QString("\nSetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer error: %1 \n").arg(console->errorCode);

    if(!(console->errorCode = GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(console->con_screenbuf, &console->conScreenBuffInfoEX)))
        console->errorMessage += QString("\nGetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx error: %1 \n").arg(console->errorCode);

    console->conScreenBuffInfoEX.dwSize.X = CONSOLE_COLUMNS;
    console->conScreenBuffInfoEX.dwSize.Y = CONSOLE_ROWS;

    if(!(console->errorCode = SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(console->con_screenbuf, &console->conScreenBuffInfoEX)))
       console->errorMessage += QString("\nSetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx error: %1 \n").arg(console->errorCode);

    if(!(console->errorCode = SetConsoleTitleW(console->consoleTitle.toStdWString().data())))
        console->errorMessage += QString("SetConsoleTitle error: %1 \n").arg(console->errorCode);

    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, FALSE);
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(catchCTRL, TRUE);

    removeCloseMenu();

    if(console->errorMessage.length() > 0){
        console->mBox.setText(console->errorMessage);
        console->mBox.show();
    }

}

void messageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg){


    if((console->con_screenbuf != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)){

        switch (type) {

        case QtDebugMsg:
            console->localMsg = console->errorMessage + "Debug: " + msg;
            WriteConsoleW(console->con_screenbuf, console->localMsg.toStdWString().data(), console->localMsg.toStdWString().length(), NULL, NULL );
            WriteConsoleA(console->con_screenbuf, "\n--\n", 4, NULL, NULL );
            break;

        case QtWarningMsg:
            console->localMsg = console->errorMessage + "Warning: " + msg;
            WriteConsoleW(console->con_screenbuf, console->localMsg.toStdWString().data(), console->localMsg.toStdWString().length() , NULL, NULL );
            WriteConsoleA(console->con_screenbuf, "\n--\n", 4, NULL, NULL );
            break;

        case QtCriticalMsg:
            console->localMsg = console->errorMessage + "Critical: " + msg;
            WriteConsoleW(console->con_screenbuf, console->localMsg.toStdWString().data(), console->localMsg.toStdWString().length(), NULL, NULL );
            WriteConsoleA(console->con_screenbuf, "\n--\n", 4, NULL, NULL );
            break;

        case QtFatalMsg:
            console->localMsg = console->errorMessage + "Fatal: " + msg;
            WriteConsoleW(console->con_screenbuf, console->localMsg.toStdWString().data(), console->localMsg.toStdWString().length(), NULL, NULL );
            WriteConsoleA(console->con_screenbuf, "\n--\n", 4, NULL, NULL );
            abort();
        }
    }
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    qInstallMessageHandler(messageHandler);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    console = new consoleT();
    initialiseConsole();

    qDebug() << "Hello World!";

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"build & run" > Default for "Run in terminal" --> Enable

to flush the buffer use this command --> fflush(stdout);
you can also use "\n" in `printf` or `cout`.