# Will qDebug cost time when CONFIG += console is not set?

Tags: c++, qt

qDebug() print out text messages on the console, according to what I know print out text message is expensive.
But if I dont set CONFIG += console, will it still cost time?
Otherwise I need to comment it one by one by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qDebug):

> This function does nothing if `QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT` was defined during compilation.

So if you want to disable `qDebug()` in release build, you can add next line to your `.pro` file (taken from [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/10178/solved-qdebug-and-debug-release/3)):

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release):DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494499/why-does-qdebug-work-in-release-builds) question.

Answer (score 0):

`qDebug()` don't cost any time, even if don't set `CONFIG+=console`, you can use it for debugging tasks during compilation.

Comment: How come that input/output operations don't cost any time? In fact, they take a whole of time.