# qt printing to terminal

Tags: linux, qt, stdout

In my QT application, I want to have it so some real-time information prints in the terminal if I run the application from the terminal.

When I use printf("print this") (either in main or during the paint event), it doesn't print until I close the gui.

Why is this, and how can I have it print information in real-time? (I'm using linux)

Thanks!

Comment: did you tried `qDebug()<< "some text";` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print to console when using Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886105/how-to-print-to-console-when-using-qt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write to stdout, you should add this `CONFIG += console` to your project file config and use `cout` of `printf` for your liking. `qDebug` prints by default to `stderr`. Check this topic for more info - [How to print to console when using Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886105/how-to-print-to-console-when-using-qt)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the default message handler sends output to stdout.  I use it that way all the time.

Comment: @JacobRobbins Yes, but unless `CONFIG += console` is added, it will not be shown, except for qDebug, becouse it sends to stderr i guess

Comment: CONFIG += console is only needed on Windows. On Unix, printf, qDebug etc. are always printed to the console (if at all, i.e. qdebug isn't disabled)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `qDebug() << ...`, `qWarning() << ...`, etc.  Don't forget to include `<QDebug>`.

Docs:  [QDebug](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdebug.html#details)

Comment: Thanks, but is this only in debug builds?

Comment: I'm guessing qDebug() prints to stderror, is there any way to print to stdout instead?

Comment: Have you tried it?  [QDebug](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdebug.html#details)

Answer (score 1):

Qt doesn't interfere with printf output. (On Windows qmake (not Qt) does, but that doesn't apply to Linux). However, consider that the buffering behavior for stdout leads to `printf("print this")` not being printed until the buffer is flushed. Try with e.g. `fflush(stdout)` or simply append a newline: `printf("print this\n")` to have the buffer flushed. That's not related to Qt at all though.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try adding `CONFIG -= app_bundle` to your `.pro` file.