# cout doesn't output to command prompt however will redirect to text file

Tags: c++, output

I'm trying out my dev environment making sure everything works and my code compiles just fine, and if I run it in QT Creator, I see the output in the command log window, but I don't see any output at the actual command prompt itself.  I can redirect the output (see picture) and it will list in a text file, but nothing on the console.  I've tried QTextSteam as well as standard cout.

```
// #include <QTextStream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 //QTextStream(stdout) << "Hello, world!" << endl;
 cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
 cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
 cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
 //cout.flush();
 return 0;
}
```

output:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\hello\release>hello.exe

C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\hello\release>hello > test.txt

C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\hello\release>type test.txt
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the text, instead of providing images of text. Command prompt, can be copy-pasted from.

Comment: I corrected myself

Comment: There is nothing in the code that would explain what you are observing. The problem might lie with your console or with how the project was compiled. But there isn't anything posted here that could explain it.

Comment: I exported the file to another computer and similar symptoms.  If there is nothing in the code to explain it.  Which stackexchange would be a better place to ask this question?

Comment: How do you compile the code?

Comment: Perhaps your question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382047/qt-printing-to-terminal) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627900/what-can-explain-stdcout-not-to-display-anything).

Comment: qmake and then mingw32-make

Comment: What happens if you compile it directly with `g++`?

Comment: "... but I don't see any output at the actual command prompt itself" - and how *exactly* did you run the program from the command line?

Comment: thank you @FrançoisAndrieux that was it!  Mark as duplicate!  add CONFIG += console to my .pro file