# GCC can't capture 'this' pointer to templated type using init-capture

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, lambda, c++14

A templated class can capture its own `this` pointer in a lambda:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
  public:
    void foo(void) {}
    auto getCallableFoo(void) {
      return [this]() { this->foo(); };
    }
};
```

This and all other `Foo` examples can be tested using the following code:

```
int main()
{
  Foo<int> f;
  auto callable = f.getCallableFoo();
  callable();
}
```

However, if instead an init-capture is used, this no longer works with GCC:

```
    auto getCallableFoo(void) {
      return [ptr = this]() { ptr->foo(); };
    }
```

Error message (from GCC 5.1):

```
error: ‘Foo<T>::getCallableFoo()::<lambda()>::__ptr’ has incomplete type
```

Clang 3.7 appears to compile and run this code without error. (I'm actually using a version compiled from source from before 3.7 was released, but I don't expect this has broken since then.)

Init-capture is supposed to behave like assignment to `auto`, but the following code appears to work without error in GCC:

```
// New method in Foo:
auto getPtr(void) {
  return this;
}

// Usage:
auto ptr = f.getPtr();
ptr->foo();
```

So why isn't the `ptr` value able to capture `this` in GCC? Is this a bug?

One other consideration is that, [according to CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture), `this` is treated as a separate *syntactical* case from every other capture-list type. So that may be one hint toward why GCC treats these cases differently. But it is not clear to me what (if any) special handling is done for this special case, or why it's a special case at all.

**EDIT:** It appears that this *does* work:

```
return [ptr = static_cast<decltype(this)>(this)]() { ptr->foo(); };
```

This makes no sense to me, because `decltype` (unlike `auto`) infers *exactly* the type of its argument, so the `static_cast` shouldn't actually be affecting anything.

**EDITS 2,3,4:** Here's a complete list of expressions that I've tried with both compilers, with comments indicating which compiler(s) accept each expression:

```
[this]() { this->foo(); };        // Both: work
[ptr = this]() { ptr->foo(); };   // GCC fails
[ptr = static_cast<decltype(this)>(this)]() { ptr->foo(); };   // Both: works (!!!)
[ptr(this)]() { ptr->foo(); };   // GCC fails
[ptr{this}]() { ptr->foo(); };   // GCC works (!!!!!!!!), Clang doesn't work (infers initializer list)
[ptr = {this}]() { ptr->foo(); };   // Both: fail (infers initializer list)
[ptr = &*this]() { ptr->foo(); };  // Both: work
[ptr = &*(this)]() { ptr->foo(); };  // Both: work
```

For `[ptr{this}]`, my version of Clang (a pre-release 3.7) warns that the interpretation will change; currently it infers an initializer list, but presumably later versions will (or already do) infer the type of `this` [in accordance with the new `auto` rules from N3922](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html).

It shocks me that GCC permits `[ptr{this}]` but not `[ptr(this)]`. I have no explanation for this.

Comment: Interesting. Note that changing it to `[ptr = static_cast<const Foo<T>* const>(this)]` works for me under GCC 4.9.3 (once `foo` and `getCallableFoo` are declared as `const`, as they should be).

Comment: @Yuushi Hm. I'd like this to work inside of a macro, `BIND_MEMBER_TO_THIS`, that simply binds an arbitrary member function to the object's `this` pointer. I'd like to implement the macro using a more generic `BIND_MEMBER_TO_OBJ_PTR` macro, which would init-capture a pointer, but for now I'm working around the (apparent) bug by simply rewriting the entire lambda using `[this]` instead of making use of the other macro. As for `foo` and `getCallableFoo`, I'm trying to be as generic as possible here--`foo()` could be either `const` or non-`const`.

Comment: Note of course that the macro can't include a cast except by using `decltype`. Aaaaaaand....it appears that `static_cast<decltype(this)>(this)`, as silly as it looks, does indeed work. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Does the same bug appear if you use a simple braced-initialiser instead of `=`? _i.e._ `[ptr(this)]() { ... }`

Comment: @paddy Excellent question. No, *but*, `[ptr{this}]` *does* work in GCC, but not in Clang. I'll edit the question to summarize which syntaxes do or don't work.

Comment: Amusingly it appears that `[ptr = &*this]` works...

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot That and the `static_cast<decltype>` weirdness seem like smoking guns that this is a bug.

Comment: I had a read through some relevant parts of the C++14 draft.  § 5.1.2 describes the grammar for lambda expressions, and it definitely looks like `ptr = this` is allowed, following the normal _initializer_ rule (§ 8.5).  There is a specific rule about `this` in captures (§ 5.1.2.8) but _init-capture_ is excepted.  Again, should be fine.  I'm guessing the incomplete type is coming from the order in which the lambda type is inferred from the template.  If you tried the same thing on a non-templated class, just out of curiosity, I expect it would work.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Actually, that does *not* seem to work for my build of GCC 5.1. Which version are you using?

Comment: @KyleStrand GCC 5.3.0

Comment: @paddy Yep, I confirmed before posting that this does not trigger on non-templated classes.

Comment: works for clang 3.4 through 3.9 SVN trunk, and for MSVC 2015 as well. You should file a gcc bug.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Oops, I typed `this->foo` instead of `ptr->foo`. Looks like `[ptr =&*this]` works on my version of GCC, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It's a bug.

This is a bug. I've submitted [a GCC bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69392) for this problem. It has now been [fixed in GCC's trunk](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=232746).

#### Workaround

As noted by Revolver_Ocelot, `&*` appears to force `g++` to perform the correct type-deduction. My current workaround (which is inside a macro taking some pointer expression that might be `this`) is therefore to capture `[ptr = &*(ptr_expr)]`.

#### Why did this happen?

As noted above, GCC's Jason Merrill has fixed this in GCC's trunk. He comments that the `this` pointer requires special handling in lambda captures; specifically, it is treated as though it were not a dependent type. Previously, this special handling applied to `[this]` but not to `[ptr = this]`.

Comment: If you are taking arbitrary pointers, I'd use unary `+` rather than `&*`.

Comment: @T.C. Any particular reason why? I don't really understand what meaning unary `+` would typically have when applied to pointers, but `&*` fairly obviously means "dereference then take the address again."

Comment: @T.C. Ah. That makes complete sense, but if it's a null pointer, I've got UB anyway because the lambda calls a function using `ptr->`.