# Subscribe more outputs to QTextStream

Tags: c++, qt, stdout, qtextstream

I was just following this topic "[How to print to console when using Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886105/how-to-print-to-console-when-using-qt)" in order to make my application work. I started to wonder- Is it possible to subscribe more outputs to a single `QTextStream`? For example, lets say when I wrote something to my QTextStream object, I want the string to be printed to stdout and a specified file as well. Would this be possible?
I would appreciate all help.

Edit:
To be more exact, I am trying to find an optimal way to send a stream either to stdout, file or file + stdout. I dont want to copy data more times that I need to. Sany hints of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

One could, theoratically, write a `QIODevice` derived class that delegates its writes to multiple other `QDIODevice` objects and then use an object of that class as the device the `QTextStream` works on.

However, what you are likely actually looking for is a logging framework.

Comment: Yes I am writing a logger singleton class.

Comment: I added more detaild to my question, maybe you could reffer?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło Your logger doesn't have to be a singleton. It'll probably be more generic and less convoluted if it isn't :)

Comment: @KubaOber I know but I am used to the schematic from regular c++. Wanted to try it out with Qt.

Comment: This *is* regular C++ :) Qt is just a framework. Singletons are to be avoided, pretty much. You can sure hold an instance in a way that's globally accessible, but that doesn't make it a singleton yet :)