# std::cout does not print to console

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015

I am developing a Qt project in C++ by using Visual Studio 2015. The project is in 64-bit Release mode. The project is working successfully. `cout` does not print to console anything. I have done those two configuration as such:

1. Project Properties/Linker/System/Subsystem is Console.
2. Tools/Options/Debugging/General/Redirect All output window text to immediate window is checked.

In order to use std::cout , related code is like that:

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    cout << "hello" << endl;

    return app.exec();
}
```

The console appears but it still does not print to console.

**Edit 1:** Actually, it opens two console windows. One of them just appears and disappears. Other one appears but there is nothing in it.

**Edit 2:** This Qt project was built firstly in Visual Studio 2013 with Qt5.5. Then I rebuilt in Visual Studio 2015 with Qt 5.8. Then, this problem has occured

Comment: Have you tried moving it outside it's structure in case it is being skipped?

Comment: How do you print to the console? What do you print? Do you flush the output? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Does that even compile?

Comment: There is no compiler error. It runs and shows the interface.

Comment: The first window, which disappears, is most likely the console window that contains output to `std::cout`. Have you tried using e.g. `qDebug() << "hello"` for output? It might be a Qt thing, that it closes the standard console that Windows opens, and creates its own console window.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried your code. Still it is the same.

Comment: Have you tried printing from your other code? The one that implements the GUI? I mean after Qt has started its event loop with `app.exec()`. Both using `qDebug()` and `std::cout`. I'm not that familiar with Qt, but maybe there are flags you can present or set in the application object to inhibit the closing of the default console?

Comment: Try running the app as admin

Comment: @BENS Running as admin didn' t work also.

Comment: Duplicate question. The answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886105/how-to-print-to-console-when-using-qt