# qDebug dosen't print anything when using vscode

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code, console, qdebug

I tried to use VSCode to code Qt program,but function qDebug doesn't print anything in console when debugging a Qt program in VSCode.However it works correctly when using QtCreator.By the way,Qt program is built by cmake in vscode.

I tried to place qDebug() in different files to test but all failed.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: windows 11. ...

Comment: `qDebug()` is printing to a special destination called "debug output", it's not `stdout` nor `stderr`. This output is usually received by the debugger when it's attached to the running process. Are you running with a debugger attached? If you do, there should be an output window that shows `qDebug()` output.
There is also a free application from Microsoft called "DebugView" that displays system-wide debug output in real time.

Answer (score 0):

qDebug() is comparable to stderr, and I think it's not really what you are looking for.
To print in a console application, if you really want to use Qt, you can do this (proposed on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886105/how-to-print-to-console-when-using-qt)):

```
QTextStream& qStdOut()
{
    static QTextStream ts(stdout);
    return ts;
}


qStdOut()<<"May the Force be with you.";
```