# qDebug() on windows cmd cerr -> cout

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, stdout, stderr

I want to see `qDebug()` messages in Windows `cmd` as qDebug() writes to `cerr` I just did

```
std::cerr.rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf());
```

Which didn't work. I still don't see the debug messages on `cmd`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Console output in a Qt GUI app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360548/console-output-in-a-qt-gui-app)

Comment: This question asks WHY exchanging rdbuf's don't work.

Comment: Can you see output written directly to `std::cout`?  If not, then this is a duplicate of the other question.