# Qt qDebug() doesn't work in Windows shell

Tags: qt, printf, console-application, qdebug

I am using a `qDebug()` of Qt Framework for `printf` something on the screen. It works just fine when I run application from Qt Creator, but when I try to execute it from Windows `cmd` it shows nothing. Why that happens?

Comment: This has been asked several times in the past. I do not have more close votes for today, but if someone has, please see it as the duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360548/console-output-in-a-qt-gui-app

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to add

```
CONFIG += console
```

to your projects `.pro` file and **do not forget** to clean and build (rebuild) your project.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I think I even tried this before, but didn't clean and build full project.

Comment: I've add recommendation to clean and build to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Run your application with

```
application.exe > log.txt 2>&1
```

It redirects stderr to stdout and stdout to a file.