# How do I configure CLion standard console output?

Tags: clion

**Problem:**
CLion doesn't output any console output for debugging purposes.

I'm using CLion with the MingW compiler and cmake. No matter whether I use:

```c++
std::cout << "Testing" << std::endl;
```

Or:

```c++
printf("Testing");
```

I don't see any console output.

**Attempts at Resolution:**

**1:**
I've checked "Run", "Debug", "Terminal" and "Cmake". I've attempted to edit my configurations but "Debug" doesn't show up.

**2:**
Next, I went to Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->CMake to edit the Generation types. I added Debug and RelWithDebInfo and still to no avail.

**3:**
I also attempted to add "-Debug" to Cmake, but I still have no output.

**4:**
The closest thing I've received for debugging is using GDB to view variable values at break points. This only works in the "RelWithDebInfo" generation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

I ended up figuring out what the problem was.

I'm developing a Qt GUI application within CLion on Windows. You have to specify a console for console output to print onto.

Call this Console() function early in your main for a console prompt to open up. Now, whenever you run

```
QDebug() << <string>;
```

or

```
std::cout << <string> std::endl;
```

You'll see your debugging statements. Hope this helps somebody else out there with the same problem.

**Code:**

```
void Console()
{
    AllocConsole();
    FILE *pFileCon = NULL;
    pFileCon = freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

    COORD coordInfo;
    coordInfo.X = 130;
    coordInfo.Y = 9000;

    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coordInfo);
    SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE| ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS);
}
```

**Source:**

I found a solution here: 
[0] [Console output in a Qt GUI app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360548/console-output-in-a-qt-gui-app)

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler solution that doesn't require adding any code. Simply add the following environment variable in your debug configuration:

```
QT_ASSUME_STDERR_HAS_CONSOLE=1
```

With this, CLion shows `QDebug` and QML's `console.*()` when started with a debugger.