# Using Visual Leak Detector with a QApplication

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, memory-leaks, visual-leak-detector

I am trying to locate the memory leaks in my Qt application. I already have used [Visual Leak Detector](http://vld.codeplex.com/) for some other projects, but VLD writes the output to the console window.

My problem now is that when using a QApplication, no console window, and therefore no output from VLD, is shown. I am using Visual Studio 2015 with the Qt VS Tools plugin.

Is there a way to force the application to show the console window? Or maybe a way to write the output generated by VLD to a file?

How I start up my application:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <vld.h>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Console output in a Qt GUI app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360548/console-output-in-a-qt-gui-app)

Comment: According to the [VLD documentation](https://vld.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Configuration%20Options&referringTitle=Documentation), you should set the `ReportTo` and `ReportFile` options in vld.ini.

Comment: @ssbssa Thank you! That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ssbssa pointed out as a comment, the problem could be solved by setting ReportTo and ReportFile in vld.ini found in the installation folder of VLD:

1. change `ReportFile =` to `ReportFile = memory_leak_report.txt` or something like that.
2. change `ReportTo = debugger` to `ReportTo = file` or `ReportTo = both`.

Now the output produced by VLD will be written to the specified file.